# Using command line to copy txt of many files and create new txt with all text

Tags: stored-procedures, text, command-line

So as an early task at a new junior developer position I was asked to go through and update thousands of old parameter data types in various stored procs. I did all the updates and loaded them to the team server and now have to push them into our SQL server so they will compile.

Last night my boss eluded to how I could pull the modified procs into a directory, then use command line to copy all text and create a new txt file that could be opened in SQL to run a mass update basically in batch mode per database.

I have almost no command line experience, can someone give me a quick overview.

My Pseudocode:

Open command line window in my UpdatedProcs folder, copy text from all files in same directory, create new text file containing all of the text (name of new file doesn't matter). Then open in SQL, look for errors one last time, and finally run.

This seems simple but I know nothing about command line.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What command line? Windows? Linux? Mac?

Comment: Windows, sorry, good lord it's been a long day. Don't think it matters, but also it's Windows 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `for /f` loop. You don't even need to copy the files from the subdirectory first. This appends all of the text files in the `Temp` subfolder (`C:\Test\Temp`) into a file named `summary.log` in the current folder (`C:\Test`):

```
c:\Test>for /f "tokens=*" %a in ("dir temp\*.txt") do type %a >> .\summary.log
```

`summary.log` now contains all of the content of the text files in a single file. You can open it with Notepad or any other text editor.

To run from a batch file, simply change the `%a` to `%%a` in both places.

```
c:\Test>copy con mergefiles.bat
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ("dir temp\*.txt") do type %%a >> .\summary.log
```

<kbd>F6</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd>

```
c:\Temp>mergefiles
```

<kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
c:\Temp>notepad summary.log
```

<kbd>Enter</kbd>